# Looking for the best way to give users access to a MongoDB database for a limited time

Tags: html, mongodb, react-native, realm

In my react-native app, users can store data in a database specific to their account at MongoDB, which is synchronized via Realm Sync.Now I want the possibility for users to have access to certain data of the user for a certain period of time.
This should work via a website as well as an app, should it be installed.

So I am looking for a solution to the problem that people who get access to data for a certain time are not logged in.

I am happy about any help

Comment: While the question is somewhat clear (albeit very broad) it's not really a good question for SO. This is a coding specific forum and good questions require code, troubleshooting and an expected outcome. There are literally 100 different ways (timers, cron jobs, cloud functions etc) to limit how long a user can be on a website or in an app - and in your case we don't know what "have access to certain data" means. I would head over the Realm forums which are a bit more free-form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jay, you are right.